# How to set meta tags using Angular universal SSR and ngx-seo plug-in? Explanation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, seo, server-side-rendering

In this example I will explain how, in Angular Universal SSR project, to implement ngx-seo plug-in created by https://github.com/samvloeberghs/kwerri-oss.

With this implementation you will have excellent SEO because the meta tags will be set on the server, not on client side. This can be achieved by the route resolver that will executed on the serve side.

Let`s start :)

1. Install the plug-in with `npm i ngx-seo`

**Update:**

1.1 Import `BrowserTransferStateModule` in your app.module.ts file
2. In your router file implement the property provided by Angular called `resolve` for every path that you will want to set meta tags, like this (*you can have separate resolver for every route if necessary*):

```
{
    path: 'path-of-your-page',
    loadChildren: () => import('.....import the module of your page....').then(m => m.ModuleName),
    resolve: { pageData: PageResolver }
}
```

3. Create the page.resolver.ts file somewhere in your project - https://angular.io/api/router/Resolve
   The resolver file will be responsible for retrieving data from your API or from the TransferState provided by Angular.
4. Import the `import { TransferState, makeStateKey } from '@angular/platform-browser';`
5. Decorate your page.resolver.ts class `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })`
6. Implement in PageResolver class resolver interface like this:
   `implements Resolve<type of the data that you manipulate>`
7. In the constructor of PageResolver class register the TransferState and SeoSocialShareService like this:

```
constructor(
    private transferState: TransferState,
    private seoSocialShareService: SeoSocialShareService
  ) { }
```

8. In the implemented method

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<type of the data that you manipulate> | Promise<any> | any 
// open the resolve method
{
```

from Resolve interface, create one const that will store the state key like this:

```
const stateKey = makeStateKey<type of the data that you manipulate>(state.url);
```

I choose the state.url as the key for the TransferState

Now everything is prepared to start setting the meta tags.
My personal choice was to use TransferState so I wont make API calls all the time through the visitor session. This is useful feature for content that wont change a lot so you can reduce API calls over that visitor session.

Next thing, if you decide to use TransferState, is to check if there is state with specific stateKey.
I choose RxJs operators so i can tap in the pipe of my API call to set the meta tags and save the response in the transfer state and also to return the state data as Observable.

```
    // check if that key exist in the transfer state
    if (this.transferState.hasKey(stateKey)) {

      // get the state data from transfer state
      const stateData = this.transferState.get<type of the data that you manipulate>(stateKey, null);

      this.seoSocialShareService.setCanonicalUrl(the domain + state.url);

      const seoData: SeoSocialShareData = {
        author: .....,
        keywords: .....,
        title: ......,
        etc.
      };

      this.seoSocialShareService.setData(seoData);

      // return the state datа as Observable
      return of(stateData);
    }
    else {

      return this.yourService.CallApiEndpoint() // httpClient call
        .pipe(
          tap({
            next: (response) => {

              this.seoSocialShareService.setCanonicalUrl(the domain + state.url);

              const seoData: SeoSocialShareData = {
                author: .....,
                keywords: .....,
                title: ......,
                etc.
              };

              this.seoSocialShareService.setData(seoData);

              // save the response in the TransferState so you can retrieve on the next request
              this.transferState.set(stateKey, response);

            }
          })
        );

    }

} 
// close the resolve method
```

So like this we have resolver that will be executed on the server side and it will set all the meta tags before that state is returned to the requester. This flow is executed whether the request is made by some crawler or web site visitor.

Next thing is to move to the view component.ts file and retrieve the resolved data from our resolver so later we can display or manipulate it.

In our component.ts file we have to register ActivatedRoute class provided by Angular in order to get the resolved data, like this:

```
constructor(
    private activatedRouter: ActivatedRoute
  ) { }
```

Now we are able to retrieve the resolved data like this somewhere in our code, usually in ngOnInit(){} method, like this:
`const pageData = this.activatedRouter.snapshot.data.pageData as type of the data that you manipulate;`
and then remove all the API calls the were in your component.ts file before integration of the resolver.
The data will be feched and transferred to your component view by the resolver.

With this we have completely integrate seo meta tags on our Angular Universal SSR app.

You can test your integration here https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Happy coding :)

Comment: Goce dispite this, it is still not setting the meta tags, I have viewed the source of the page.
It still has the HTML of the index.html file

Comment: @teebo have you installed this package ng add @nguniversal/express-engine? [link](https://angular.io/guide/universal)

Comment: And you are starting the app with npm run dev:ssr?

Comment: @teebo one more think that i missed, in app module did you import BrowserTransferStateModule?

Comment: Yes I did and the dev:srr script works but when building using `npm run build:ssr && npm run serve:ssr` there are no errors but still view page source does not show updated tags

Comment: @teebo and you are setting the tags in the resolver? this is weird man...

Comment: Goce, thank you, I will get to the bottom of it, I will let you know what I have found